# Sq-Server when we have to use cursor?

Tags: sql-server, performance, cursor

I know that using cursor cause less performance and Ideally we should use it as little as possible
so I want to know that is it a situation that we have to use cursor?

Comment: One example is when one needs to execute a stored procedure for each row returned by a query. However, it would be better in that case to refactor the procedure to perform a set-based operation on the same results returned by the query.

Comment: There are very few times you need to *really* use one as it's almost always going to be a case that a set based method is better. Personally the only time I find I need to use one is when using `sp_send_dbmail` to send multiple emails from a dataset, row by row.